# Tweepy TypeError: Stream() takes no arguments

Tags: python, tweepy

Get error message all the time, only with stream. Anyone have an idea what this can be?

latest Tweepy, Python 3.10.0 on Windows 10 and RaspOS. Not working..

---

[stream = Stream(auth, listener)
TypeError: Stream() takes no arguments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOTTu.png)

---

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avBhs.png)

```
import tweepy
import keys
class MaxListener(tweepy.Stream):

    def on_data(self, raw_data):
        self.process_data(raw_data)
        return True

    def process_data(self, raw_data):
        print(raw_data)

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:
            #returning False in on_data disconnects the stream
            return False
class Stream():

    def super__init__(self, auth, listener):
        self.stream = tweepy.Stream(auth=auth, listener=listener)

    def start(self, keyword_list):
        self.stream.filter(track=keyword_list)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    listener = MaxListener('keys'...)


    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(keys.API_KEY, keys.API_SECRET_KEY)
    auth.set_access_token(keys.ACCESS_TOKEN, keys.ACCES_TOKEN_SECRET)

    stream = Stream(auth, listener)
    stream.start(['Python'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Stream` is your own defined class rather than [`tweepy.Stream`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.1.0/stream.html#tweepy.Stream) or a subclass of `tweepy.Stream`, and it doesn't have an `__init__` defined to accept any arguments/parameters for initialization.

You're also using syntax from Tweepy v3. [Tweepy v4.0.0](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/releases/tag/v4.0.0) changed `Stream` so as to accept each credential as a parameter and merged `StreamListener` into `Stream`.

For code block usage, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.